# How can I do it in Flutter after the splash screen, the logo goes to the top and the login page appears at the bottom?

Tags: ios, flutter, animation, bloc, cubit

I need this case. I use cubit for state managament. I have auth contorl in initCubit and user if not loged, svg logo be smaller and moving top and login widget (2 textbox and 1 button) coming to bottom. How can i do?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider<SplashCubit>(
        create: (context) => SplashCubit()..getSplash(),
        child: Center(
          child: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/svgs/thefoodrunnerslogo.svg',
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .8,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is my body Splash Screen